# Restore a Message object from what was saved with the writeTo method

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

if I save a `Message` object content to a file using the `writeTo` method, is it possible recreate the object from that file content?

I know a `Message` has much more information than the one saved with the `writeTo` method, like the store, the folder and so on.. but I'm not interested to these information.

Should I parse the file in order to retrieve the information and set every field in a new `Message` object? Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage(Session, InputStream)](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#MimeMessage%28javax.mail.Session,%20java.io.InputStream%29) constructor can be used to parse a MIME message.

```
try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("foo.eml")) {
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage((Session) null, in);
        //...
    }
```